# Study of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^\alpha(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}}-\log{(n+1)}+\log{n}+\cos{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, parametric

For $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$ I want to study the behaviour of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^\alpha(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}}-\log{(n+1)}+\log{n}+\cos{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$$
I have thought to apply the asymptotic test but in order to be able to apply this I have to check if this is a series of positive term, so: **how can I prove this?**

Now:
$1)\sinh\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^4})$
$2) \cos{\frac{1}{n}}=1-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$
$3)\log({\frac{n}{n+1}})=-\log(1+{\frac{1}{n}})=-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{3n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})$
And so:
$$n^\alpha(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}}-\log{(n+1)}+\log{n}+\cos{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\\ =n^\alpha(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^4})-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{2n^2}-\frac{1}{3n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3})-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o(\frac{1}{n^3}))\\ =n^\alpha(\frac{-1}{6n^3}+o(\frac{1}{n^3}))=-\frac{1}{6n^{3-\alpha}}+o(\frac{1}{n^{3-\alpha}})$$
So the series converges when $3-\alpha<1$ and diverges when $3-\alpha\geq 1$.
**Am I right?**

For the first question I can say as suggested in an answer that $n^\alpha(\sinh{\frac{1}{n}}-\log{(n+1)}+\log{n}+\cos{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=-\frac{1}{6n^{3-\alpha}}+o(\frac{1}{n^{3-\alpha}})<0$, so the general term of the series is eventually negative. **Am I right?**

Comment: It is better to write $$
 - \log (n + 1) + \log n =  - \log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$

Comment: @Gary thanks to your suggestion I have edited my question with my full attempt, can you check it please? Very thanks!

Comment: Your approximation for the $\cos$ is not correct. $\cos x= 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots$. Could you please revise your question?

Comment: I have used this approximation...I have written before the cosine with respect to the logarithm...

Comment: Note that you are missing the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ in the approximation for the cosine. It is not $\cos x =1-x^2 +\cdots$. Can you see what I mean?

Comment: So it is not true that $cos(1/n)-1=1/2n^2+o(1/n^2)$?

Comment: You used $\cos(1/n)=1-1/n^2 +o(1/n^2)$, which is incorrect. It is $\cos(1/n)=1-1/(2n^2)+o(1/n^2)$. Look at your 2) for the $\cos$, you are missing the factor $1/2$. Can you see it?

Comment: @Gary now I have corrected thanks! What do you think now?

Comment: I cleaned it up a bit. The final conclusion about $3-\alpha$ is incorrect. Think about it. Also, delete the last paragraph. It is irrelevant now.

Comment: I can't understand why it is not correct...can you help me?

Comment: It diverges if $3 - \alpha  \le 1$ and converges if $3-\alpha >1$. The power of $n$ in the denominator is $3-\alpha$. By the $p$-series test this power has to be larger than $1$ for the series to converge.

Comment: Ah ok yeah I don't know why I have completely confused this thing...Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124372/discussion-between-sisi-and-gary).

Answer (score 1):

We have $$
n^\alpha\left(\frac{1}{n^2+n}-\frac{2n+1}{2(n^2(n+1))}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=\frac{n^\alpha}{n(n+1)}\left(-\frac1{2n}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)<0$$ for $n$ sufficiently large.    It's just as good to have all the terms negative as positive, of course, so you can proceed.

Perhaps I ought to add that I haven't checked your calculations in detail.